# Gradle : Get all files in a dependency from maven repository

Tags: maven, gradle, nexus

I want to add all the files available in a dependency to my artifacts so I can upload that dependency to another Nexus repository.

My dependency contains 15 files stored in my Nexus repository under the same GAV :

```
myproject.jar
myproject.jar.md5
myproject.jar.sha1

myproject-sources.jar
myproject-sources.jar.md5
myproject-sources.jar.sha1

myproject.tgz
myproject.tgz.md5
myproject.tgz.sha1

myproject.pom
myproject.pom.md5
myproject.pom.sha1

maven-metadata.xml
maven-metadata.xml.md5
maven-metadata.xml.sha1
```

The `-sources.jar`file has a `<classifier>sources</classifier>`property, the tgz and pom files have an `<extension>`property and the others have nothing special.

The thing is I would like to avoid hardcoding as much as possible, to be able to pass only the GAV parameters to my script and it can handle all the fetching and releasing on its own for any GAV, no matter what files are available.

The solution I'm working on right now is to query directly the Nexus repo to get the files list with an url like this :

`http://mynexushost:8081/nexus/service/local/repositories/snapshots/content/${group}/${artifact}/${version}/`

That sends me a JSON (with the accept header set to `application/json`) containing the URLs and stuff I need to retreive all the files available, download them and add them to my artifacts, then upload it to my target repository.

I'm pretty sure this solution works, but it's definitiely not the "Gradle way" to do it since it ties me to Nexus and does not use the builtin maven dependency resolution utilities.

How could I solve that without querying the Nexus API?

Comment: Can you declare a Gradle dependency? Why do you need to get all the specific files?

Comment: I want to reproduce the same exact GAV in another Nexus repo. Maybe I don't need to specify all the files one by one but using the defaut gradle way to handle dependencies I only get the `myproject.jar`file. And I don't want to hardcode the extensions in my deployment script, I want to keep it generic.

Comment: Does that mean you're [deploying some artifacts to another repository](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/maven_plugin.html#sec:deploying_to_a_maven_repository)?

Comment: Yes, that is what I want to do. However this only supports deploying files that are listed in my artifacts so I have to download them somewhere. And using a dependency to download the files does not allow me to download all the required files. This is the process actually in place, which works for the dependencies with only one jar but not for the ones with more files like the one I gave in example.

Comment: @Johnride Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: @JaredBurrows I ended up querying Nexus API. Then we switched to Artifactory and I had to adjust my script to work with that other API. So no, I never found a pure maven/gradle way.

Answer (score 1):

I have created a tool called the Maven Repository Provisioner that pretty much accomplishes this. You can check it out at https://github.com/simpligility/maven-repository-tools

It is used in production for exactly the purpose you want, but it also calculates and provisions all the transitive dependencies and needed parent poms. Check it out and if it doesnt fully do what you want... I take pull requests ;-)

Comment: That sounds great, the thing is I want to run a gradle script to do this as all my build and deployment is built with gradle. Plus with the time I was able to create one myself. Sadly I can't open source it as I developed it for a client. Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: You could wrap a gradle plugin around my tool. In fact I plan to do a Maven plugin for it down the road.